# How to flag off-topic question for a site not listed in the menu?

Tags: support, flags, migration, off-topic

I wanted to flag a question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/13074711/1176601 - as off-topic and suggest moving to http://security.stackexchange.com, but I didn't find it on the list of other-topic sites..

What should I do in cases like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should flag for moderation attention, and ask for the question to be migrated. Keep in mind that if a question is on topic for Stack Overflow, it will *not* be migrated, even if it's a bit more suitable on another site.

Comment: thanks, what is your opinion about this particular question?

Comment: @deathApril I'm not very familiar with Sec.SE's scope. Their [FAQ](http://security.stackexchange.com/faq) mentions "web app hardening", so it's probably on topic, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: We could accept this as on topic on Security - feel free to flag for migration :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop yep, i already flagged for moderator attention and Kev♦ found the flag helpfull..

Comment: no worries - I did too. Sometimes mod flags from the destination site get acted on a bit faster :-)